# QuickSort not implementing on a run?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

For a project, my code is supposed to run two sorting algorithms with the same unsort list. The unsorted list is an array filled with random integers. I ran my code and one of the two sorting methods work. The quicksort method does not appear when I run my code. I tried another way and I get the error code

> |The method quickSort(int[], int, int) in the type test is not applicable for the arguments (Class, int, int).|

Any reason why my quicksort is not showing up when I run my code.
Here is part of my code.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int [] unsort= new int [100];
    //creates an array of a 100 objects

    for(int i = 0;i < unsort.length; i++) {
        unsort[i] = generator.nextInt(99)+1;
    }
    // fills the array with 100 random numbers


    System.out.println("unsorted :"+Arrays.toString(unsort);
    Quicksort(unsort,0,unsort.length-1);
    System.out.println("quicksort:"+ Arrays.toString(unsort));
    //goes to each sorting method and run the sorting program
}

 public static void Quicksort(int[] unsort, int low, int high) {
     if (low >= high && unsort.length==0){
            return;  
     }
     //Checks if the array is already sorted or empty, it will return the array


    int i= low;
    int j = high;
    //creates a smaller reference to use in the if/while statements

    int pivot = unsort[i+(j-i)/2];
    //the pivot is middle value of the array 


    while(i<=j ) {
        while( unsort[i]< pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while(unsort[i]>pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        // while statements keeps all numbers less than the pivot to the low bounds
        //and all the numbers higher than the pivot to the right

        if(i<=j) {
            int temp = unsort[i];
            unsort[i]= unsort[j];
            unsort[j]=temp;
            i++;
            j--;
            //comparisons++;
        }
        //if the selected object is bigger than the object in the low bound
        // It will swap the placement of both numbers

        if(low<j) Quicksort(unsort,low,j);

        if (i< high) Quicksort(unsort,i,high);

        // its the recursive method to keep all the high and low numbers in their bounds

    }
}
```

Comment: why is the methode quicksort static? I think its always better to create an object, that contains the methode quicksort and do not call it from a static content.

Comment: The quicksort method contains an infinite loop, so the print statement is never executed. Don´t have the time tough to spot the exact line.

Comment: `unsort.length==0` will never be true (because it is allocated to have 100 elements) so `if (low >= high && unsort.length==0){ return; }` will never happen.